# Auth0 how can i deploy my next.js application to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, authentication, url, next.js, auth0

This is my application deployed on Vercel: https://budgetinator.vercel.app/

Whenever i click on the login button error 500 internal server error occurs.

This in the .env.local of my application

```
AUTH0_BASE_URL='http://localhost:3000'
AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL='https://dev-wyibmj01.us.auth0.com'
```

Now using localhost:3000 is works fine, but i want to deploy my application.

I also already changed the url's on auth0 dashboard:

[image]

However, it still cant really connect. What do i need to do?

Comment: Do you have an environment configuration for production? `.env.local` refers to your local (dev).

Comment: Shouldn't the second allowed callback URL be `https://budgetinator.vercel.app/api/auth/callback`? Have you also setup the environment variable properly in Vercel? See https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push up a .env.production file with these values matching to the environment variables you have in Vercel. It should not contain any sensitive information because it's being pushed to your repo!

```
AUTH0_SECRET=${AUTH0_SECRET}
AUTH0_BASE_URL=${AUTH0_BASE_URL}
AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL='https://precisionproco-dev.eu.auth0.com'
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=${AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=${AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

I'm having the issue of the login page showing up, however, on the Vercel live site, it doesnt re-direct to the home page, i get a blank page with a 400 error. It works fine on localhost and redirects back, but doesnt on the Vercel site.